# 500 internal server error when using app engine, trying to upload an image

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, http-post, multipart

I'm trying to upload an image from android to app engine(Java). Im using BlobstoreService to store images. Here is what my project looks like:

On the server side, I do the following to generate the upload url

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String uploadURL = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");
resp.getWriter().print(uploadURL);
```

On the client(Android) side, I get this when printed

http://mydomain.com/_ah/upload/AMmfu6YehP-o-VUwRXmCfJzYOZ1jvXiD33fF-LhZw5nO6XIwCE0cD0-zTwvg9beO0gXeNjuNG_wMNwnX9Yr5I3BVUdyolby4bnXQyHBWA-fpJNfR7sfqqukOIuMEa3EubgNWTj7q0bxY/ALBNUaYAAAAAUsDnWeK48TX7bblzmE0jUNgf22o4-IXP/

Please note the last character in the url, the '/'. When I use this as url to build httpurl 'HttpPost(mUploadURL)', I get Illegal character in path at index 231(which is '/') of url. So my question is -- what am I doing wrong here?

So, I removed the '/' from url as below:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest = null;
        postRequest = new HttpPost(mUploadURL.substring(0, mUploadURL.length()-2));
        try {
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        reqEntity.addPart("title", new StringBody("new title"));

        try{
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d("test", "mPhoto: " + mPhoto);
            mPhoto.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "image/jpeg", "forest.jpg");
            reqEntity.addPart("picture", bab);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("test", "e: " + e);
            reqEntity.addPart("picture", new StringBody(""));
        }
        postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
        Log.d("test", "after post: " + s.toString());
        return s.toString();
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            Log.d("test", "ee: " + ee);
            return "";
        }
```

After post, I get this as result

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"><title>500 Server Error</title></head><body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff><h1>Error: Server Error</h1><h2>The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.<p>Please retry your last submission.</p><p>If the problem persists, please contact the person responsible for the application you're using, or, if you are that person, <a href="http://code.google.com/appengine/community.html">report</a> your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.</h2></body></html>
```

My second question is -- what is wrong in the multipart post code? I use app engine as backend. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have a look in your logs and see what the stacktrace is for the error.

Comment: on the server side(cloud console), there is no exception or any log being printed for the http-post.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem 1. You just have to do returnedUrl.trim() before you use that for your post request. This solved problem 2 as well. Thanks.